# missing hyper refs in a reduced pdf

Tags: hyperref

I can reduce af pdf produced by (pdf-)LaTeX with a ghost-script:

> gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/default -dDOPDFMARKS -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH -r300 -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.pdf

BUT after reducing the pdf the new reduced pdf lacks any hyper-refs.

Is there any option to add to the script to retain the hyper-refs after reducing the pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links need a specific flag so that ghostscript preserves them.

Currently the only way to set this flag is to use the `pdfa` option of hyperref (which can have other perhaps not wanted effects).