# Autoref and TOC links lost due to Ghostscript compression (-dPrinted = false already set)

Tags: hyperref, latexmk, links, ghostscript

I built a latex document and compress it afterwards with Ghostscript (gs). While some links are retained, e.g. urls, the links in the TOC and links created with *autoref* are not retained.

Adding the option `-dPrinted=false` option as described in [Local hyperlinks broken after PDF processing with Ghostscript](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/245801/local-hyperlinks-broken-after-pdf-processing-with-ghostscript) or [Set the print flag on links with hyperref to preserve them with Ghostscript >= 9.25](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/456896/set-the-print-flag-on-links-with-hyperref-to-preserve-them-with-ghostscript-9) did not work for the autoref or TOC links.

Would really appreciate some help or hints how to solve this!

**MWE**

```
all:
    latexmk -pdf -halt-on-error -shell-escape main.tex

reduced:
    gs  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
        -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
        -dNOPAUSE -dQUIET -dBATCH \
        -dPrinted=false \
        -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
        -sOutputFile=main_reduced.pdf \
        main.pdf
```

```tex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{scrreprt}


\usepackage[]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents    
    
    \chapter{1}
    \label{chap:1}
    This is a reference to a figure \autoref{fig:figure} 
    
    \section{Test}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        Figure
        \caption{This is a figure}
        \label{fig:figure}
    \end{figure}
    \href{mailto:hello@world.com}{hello@world.com}
\end{document}
```

Ghostscript 9.56.1 (2022-04-04)

MacOS 12.4

Comment: `-dPrinted=flase ` look false ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I checked again but it does not work either..

Comment: you are also missing the pdfa option, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480700/2388

Comment: I have already tried that before and `href` already works.  My assumption is that there is a difference in the implementation of `href` and `autoref` because href works just fine.

Comment: hm yes, the destinations are gone. Ask on the ghostscript list. If they tell you what flag is needed one can perhaps activate it in hyperref.

Comment: Is there a specific website other than their bug tracker to contact them?